# Set lookup variable to be the value of an expression

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This is the sample of my `noteCollection`'s document

```js
{
  title: "Some title",
  body: "Descreptive body",
  contributedBy: [
    {
     contributorId: ObjectId(5353ff535f5f3a5)
    }
  ] // for some reason, this field has to be an array of objects
}
```

Now, while using `$lookup` to "lookup" for the contributor, I need the `contributorId` field

The problem is, I don't know how to express `contributedBy[0].contributorId` in MongoDB query way.

```js
// lookup aggregation

{
  from: 'contributors',
  as: 'contributor',
  let: {'contributorUserId': '$contributedBy[0].contributorId'}, // here, how to get the value of `contributorId` property of the 0th element in `contributedBy` field
  pipeline: [
    {$match: {
     $expr: {$eq: ['$_id', '$$contributorUserId']} 
    }}   
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to join those two collections by only one `contributedBy.contributorId` at `0th` index, use [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) operator:

```js
db.noteCollection.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'contributors',
            as: 'contributor',
            let: { 
                'contributorUserId': {
                    $arrayElemAt: ['$contributedBy.contributorId', 0]
                }
            },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: { $eq: ['$_id', '$$contributorUserId'] }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
])
```

If you want to join the two collections w.r.t to their reference `_id`s then use [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) operator:

```js
db.noteCollection.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'contributors',
            as: 'contributor',
            let: { 
                'contributorUserIds': '$contributedBy.contributorId'
            },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: { $in: ['$_id', '$$contributorUserIds'] }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
])
```